# What is the difference between that ways, when assign an array to pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, assign

When we need to assign an array to pointer, we doing something like that.

```
int numbers[] = {7,5,9,3};
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr = &numbers[0];  // <<
```

Also we can do same thing by doing this.

```
int numbers[] = {7,5,9,3};
int *ptr = NULL;
ptr = numbers;  // <<
```

**What is the difference between two ways ?**
**And which one is the Recommended ?**

Comment: IIRC, the term is "array [pointer] decay" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying, perhaps

Comment: There's no difference. Pick whichever has your fancy. The former is explicit, the latter is short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same thing. The expression `a[i]` is the same as `*(a + i)`, so `&a[i]` is the same as `&*(a + i)`, which is defined to be identical to `a + i` (without even evaluating the dereference). For `i = 0` this means that `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. The name of the array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please Clarify this part `The name of the array decays to a pointer`

Comment: @LionKing: When you use `numbers` as an expression (a so-called *id-expression*), then in most cases it's value is an `int` pointer which points to the first element of the array; it's value does *not* have array type. This is called "decay". There are no "array values" in C.

Answer (score 1):

No difference (except when they are the oprand of `sizeof` operator). In both case you are assigning address of the first element of array. `&numbers[0]` assign the address of the first element of the array while `numbers` will decay to pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: It should be worth noting that although there is no difference in this case, there are times when `array` and `&array[0]` are not the same (e.g. when it is used as an operand to `sizeof`).

Answer (score -3):

They will both give you the same value, however there is slightly a difference. When you do

```
ptr = &numbers[0];
```

you are adding two unnecessary steps, a dereference and a "address of" operation, so using

```
ptr = numbers;
```

would be more performant, unless the compiler optimizes it away. It may be useful to think of `int numbers[] = ...;` as `int *numbers = ...`

Comment: If a compiler doesn't produce the same output for both situations it might be time to find a new compiler.

Comment: "tr = numbers; would be more performant" - uggh... let us try wake up and live in the 21th century...